# How can I modify this Ordering?

Tags: scala, traits

I have this piece of code which call the default comparator for `Longs`:

```
val ordering = implicitly[Ordering[Long]]
```

How can I create my own ordering and call it with `implicitly`?

I tried this:

```
trait MyOrdering extends Ordering[Long] {
  override def compare(x: Long, y: Long): Int = x compare y
}

val ordering = implicitly[MyOrdering]
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Change `trait MyOrdering extends Ordering[Long] {` with `implicit object MyOrdering extends Ordering[Long] {` or with `implicit val MyOrdering: Ordering[Long] = new Ordering[Long] {`.

Comment: Also, you should not ask for your concrete implicit, but rather for the type it is providing. - `implicitly[Ordering[Long]]`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put an instance of your new `Ordering` implementation into the implicit namespace.

```
implicit val mo :MyOrdering = new MyOrdering {}

val ordering = implicitly[MyOrdering]
```

You could also change your `trait` to an `implicit object` but you'll also need to modify the `implicitly` parameter.

```
implicit object MyOrdering extends Ordering[Long] {
  override def compare(x: Long, y: Long): Int = x compare y
}

val ordering = implicitly[MyOrdering.type]
```